# C# Ordered enumerable - An object reference is not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception, enumerable

I have the following code:

```
// OnlineAccountCategory is a class
var itemsByCategory = Items.GroupBy(x => x.OnlineAccountCategory); 
foreach (var items in itemsByCategory)
...
```

Items is a list that contains 1 item. Item has a `OnlineAccountCategory` which is not `null`. But when I'm trying to go through `itemsByCategory` I receive a `NullReferenceException`. In the debug mode I can see that `itemsByCategory` is a `GroupedEnumerable` but inside of it if I expand the Results View it will tell that 'An object reference is not set to an instance of an object'.

I don't quite understand what's the problem with this code as `GroupBy()` goes fine without any exception but then breaks in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that OnlineAccountCategory is a **reference** type property (and not a string or something like that). Grouping by reference types uses method `GetHashCode()` of a class by which the grouping is occuring.

And the key thing is if the `GetHashCode()` method throws an exception (for instance, if it relies on working with a property of our object which is `null`) the `GroupBy()` method won't fail. It will just return a `GroupedEnumerable` that contains an exception inside for some reason.

```
// Trying to add this to watch:     
Items.First().OnlineAccountCategory.GetHashCode()   
// Receiving: 
'Items.First().OnlineAccountCategory.GetHashCode()' threw an exception of type 
'System.NullReferenceException' int {System.NullReferenceException}
```

Hence, when we are trying to access an element of the collection, it falls with `NullReferenceException`.

To solve this we have two approaches:

1. Override the `GetHashCode` method of our `OnlineAccountCategory`
   so it will not fail on incorrect values and instead of throwing an
   exception will return something like 0.
2. Group by some value type instead (for instance,
       `OnlineAccountCategory.Id`). It will group by it and hence won't
       fail.

**Update:**
The problem will occur **only** when the `GetHashCode()` method was already implemented incorrectly (which was implemented in the base class in my case). The default reference comparer will work with that as expected.

The `GetHashCode()` method for me looks like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // Title is a string
    return Title != null ? Title.GetHashCode() : 0;
}
```

So I don't really understand why does it break with a NullReferenceException here.

Comment: Your first "solution" absolutely make no sense. If you don't override `GetHashCode`, the default reference equality comparer implementation is used, which never throw NRE. Looks like your issue is the opposite - you **did** override `GetHashCode` and implemented it wrongly, which is simply a bug. Also, regarding "is a reference type (and not a string or something like that)" -  FYI `string` is also a **reference type**.

Comment: "this problem with occur only with reference types such as classes, not strings" - the problem does _not_ occur on _any_ type _unless you implement `GetHashCode` incorrectly_.  There's nothing wrong with grouping by a reference type in general.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, maybe I was somewhat unclear. That's what I wrote: "is if the `GetHashCode` method throws an exception (for instance, if it relies on working with a property of our object which is null)" So I meant if the implementation is incorrect and throws an exception we will get such situation here. I understand that string is a reference type so that's why I mentioned that the problem will only occur with classes where the implementation of `GetHashCode` could be incorrect (not with reference types such as strings where we can't make an incorrect implementation of `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you got the problem solved but I don't think you fully understand the reason for the error.

> I don't quite understand what's the problem with this code as GroupBy() goes fine without any exception but then breaks in the foreach loop.

The reason you're not seeing the error until `foreach` is executed is *deferred execution*.  `GetHashCode` is not called *until you try to enumerate the collection*.  If `GetHashCode` is throwing a `NullReferenceException` then you won't know that until you execute the query with `foreach`, which is when the groups are actually created.

Certainly the *root* cause is your incorrect `GetHashCode` method, which can easily be detected in unit tests.

Note that it's perfectly fine to group by reference types without overriding `GetHashCode`, since any null values will just be put into a group with a `null` key (Linq will not try and call `GetHashCode` on the null reference).  You only *need* to override `GetHashCode` when you want to define equality for different instances based on values of the instance, instead of using reference equality by default.

Comment: I think you're right about deferred execution, thanks for the clarification. The problem for me was that my OnlineAccountCategory property was NOT a null so the implementation of GetHashCode() was failing with an exception.

Comment: deferred execution could be a problem at least in my case, putting .ToList() before foreach has solved my problem. Will have to check for a couple of day to see if the error has goes away.